# GUI - Call setters or dispatch events?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns

I'm in the process of developing an advanced modular GUI system. I need it to be as flexible as possible and hopefully as useful to as many people as possible (however it will be reasonably niche).

The part of my design that is causing me to think, is how each component should best interact with the rest of the application.

I see two approaches:

1. Pass in the class and name of a setter, on which the component should act upon. This still allows events to be dispatched from within the setter if desired.
2. Pass in a CustomEvent which the component should dispatch, with relevant data. Though I feel this may lead to a lot of Event Listeners, and extra complexity.

**But What is best practice? What are the pros and cons of each? Is there a better method?**

1. Basic example:

   ```
   public class Button extends Sprite
   {
   private var _property:String;
   private var _object:*;

   public function Button(label:String, object:*, property:String) 
   { 
       _property = property;
       _object = object;
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  onClick);
   } 

   private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
       _object[_property] = "Changed";
   }

   }
   ```
2. Basic Example:

   ```
   public class Button extends Sprite
   {
   private var _event:GuiEvent;

   public function Button(label:String, event:GuiEvent) 
   {
       _event = event;
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  onClick);
   }

   private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
       dispatchEvent(new GuiEvent(_event.type, "Changed"));
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: i would use option 1 (binding) for editors (like lists , input fields and such elements) and event or method closures for buttons . I rebuild a little minimalcomps for DataBinding , You can check it here : http://turbosqel.pl/mix/   . Events are good , but need more code and its harder to change something .

Comment: Yeah I see a few gui frameworks use that kind of system

Answer (score 0):

If you want your GUI framework to be useful to everybody, you should use standard events instead of inventing new ones. The second option is the way to go but you should try to keep things simple. The code you wrote in example 2 seems incredibly complicated. It could simply be written like that:

```
public class Button extends Sprite
{

    public function Button(label:String) 
    {
    }

}
```

Then anybody can handle clicks using the event they know:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

Comment: I doubt that will work for the advance controls, which may actually consist of many components. There would be no standard Events that would make sense? For instance take a control that consists of an x/y fader and several check boxes, what event would you listen for? Plus if you pass all the events in that are to be dispatched, would it not make more sense for a controller to listener to the GUI container and handle them?

Comment: For something as basic as a click, it makes sense to use the event already defined instead of forcing the user to learn new events. If a component is more complex, of course you might need to create custom events.

Comment: Events are better for async operations and control . In this simple case of button might be ok , but think about TextFields , sliders , CheckBox and other tools . You can always write line item.addEventListener(...); and creat function doSmth(e:Event) , i would make item.bind(target,key); with save lot of time and writting.

Answer (score 0):

*Slightly offtopic and not really an answer to your question:*

Why recreate something that already exists? There are already proven libraries with GUI components.

For example, take the AS3 Temple Library
http://code.google.com/p/templelibrary/

It has all types of form element components; checkbox, radiobutton, combobox, inputfield, filefield, scrollcomponent, date selectors, (step)sliders, list, scrollbars, autocomplete field and all types of buttons. 
It also has a Form class, whichs helps in validation, deliver data to any type of services. It also manages the tabindexes right and all controls can be used with keyboard too, just like everyone expects it to work. There are also codecomponents for a mockup, but you can use the same code to style it with endless creativity with library items, timelines, or however you want it. Most of the gui components are designed so they can be extended to make it fit your needs.

Most of the gui components work with normal eventlisteners (most dispatch Event.CHANGE when content change), in most cases there is no need to wrap it into new type of events.

Comment: thanks for the link. However to answer your question - Because I am doing this as a learning exercise, and also because many of my components will be rather different to that of what I have seen in many library's so far.